# Keypad Conundrum

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Tonight I had to work late at the office to fix a small, but critical bug. Most people leave early and by the time I was done working, I was the only person left in the office.

I quickly gathered my things and made my way to the exit, only to find the the electronic lock was refusing to accept my password. I tried a few more times, pressing the "1" button four times. (Yes, our office security password is 1111).

Nothing happened and only then did I notice the post-it note next to the keypad.

[image]
[image]

I can't figure out this puzzle. I thought that these guys were done with all these "tests".
Surely there must be some more information to be able to solve this puzzle.
Can you please help me? I really don't want to spend the night at the office!

**What is the 16 digit password?**

Answer (score 3):

[This is only a partial answer.]

You take a closer look at the note.

> Hey, what's that? There are some grooves on the paper as if someone had written something on the previous sticky note with a hard pencil. With a soft pencil you brush the grooved surface and reveal some numbers:
>
>   [image: the sticky note reveals its mystery]
>
>  Quickly, you transcribe the numbers:
>
>  016:−6(28,12,30,30) −4(12,5,15) −7(12,15,10,11,6,15,12,21)

Comment: Good job spotting that. Love the in character reponse.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: M Oehm found this before me!

## Partial Answer

See [M Oehm's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57858/40820) answer.

Note that:

> Quite a few of the numbers inside the parentheses are divisible by 3.

### Other observations

Edited after comments from the OP.

1. <s>The middle paragraph consists of four lines that have the following number of words each: 11, 8, 11, 8. This seems to be intentional, because the word "spend" would definitely fit in the previous line.</s>
2. The following phrases contain exactly 16 letters: "It has been too long", "Since we tested you" and "The first number is". Maybe this is just a coincidence.
3. <s>The last sentence has no period. This is odd, because everything else is "correctly" written.</s>
4. There are <s>at least 3 different characters</s> **two characters** for '0' (**One wide and one narrow**, "The two narrow ones[...] are intended to [be] the the same character"):
   [image]

Comment: Good observations. Just to clarify points 3 and 4. The period being missing on the last sentence is a mistake. So no clues or insights there. And for the O character there are only two different ones the wide one and the narrow one. The two narrow ones you have show are intended to the the same character.

Comment: To stop you and others from going down the wrong rabbit hole. The spacing and paragraphs of the message are irrelavant. If it looks odd then its probably because i got tired with making it look nice.

Comment: Thanks! I edited a bit, so people don't waste their brainpower on non-clues :)